# PayPal Smart Buttons: Is there any way onApprove runs without the payment having completed?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

So I have a website that uses PayPal smart buttons and I have a code that sends a the buyer the product when he buys the it. It uses a PHP file to send the product.

I have javascript code that calls PHP when the onApprove function runs.

I know that it is not the safest way to do but I found it really hard to use the API and it would be a lot of time to do it so I decided to do it this way.

But I ran into a problem when I don't receive the money on PayPal, but the program send the product to them. It sometimes works and sometimes not.

I am sure that the PHP code can only run when the onApprove runs so that is not the problem.

**Is there any way that onApprove runs without the payment having completed?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely. `onApprove` runs whenever the payment is *approved* by the customer, meaning they clicked on the final approval action, usually phrased "Pay Now".  This does *not* mean a payment has been captured/completed resulting in a PayPal transaction.

Normally in `onApprove` you do something like call `actions.capture()` , so if that is successful (and only if that is successful) you would want to trigger your PHP code. A more secure implementation would be to call your PHP code and have it do a v2/orders capture API call on the server side, but that is up to you. Here is a demo of such a server-side integration pattern: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Alternatively, you could also try defining an `onComplete` function to call your PHP code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. So I do have an `actions.capture()` in my code. Here is my code: `onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                  //This is where i send the product
                });
            },`

Comment: Do you check if the capture was successful before sending your product?

Comment: I have sent my code, that is all it does or checks. Can you send me an example of what do you mean?

Comment: If you don't understand what I am saying, try using `onCompleted` instead

Comment: Can you send another answer with the example of what should I change in my code or what should I type? I have sent my code. What should I change in it? Also I have searched for OnCompleted and I couldn't find anything about what it does or how should I Implement it. Can you send an example I would really appreciate it.

Comment: No, I don't have an example. And sorry, it's "onComplete" as I said before. Try that if you can't figure out how to use the details object and check whether a capture is successful.

Comment: You can see my current script in my first comment, what should I type in to check if a capture is successful or not. Is “onComplete” a function like “onApprove” only it runs when a payment is successful?

Comment: As I mentioned, check the details in your function. You have a function that is accepting a parameter named "details". There are things in this parameter.  As I also mentioned earlier,  you could alternatively try defining an `onComplete` function -- which, yes, would be like onApprove but only when successfully captured.  You do need an onApprove function that tells it to do the capture, in case this is not obvious to you.

Comment: I know what you are telling me to do, but I am asking how to do it. Yes there is a details parameter but there are a lot of things in this parameter such as the email of the buyer and stuff like that. What should I retrive from this parameter? like `if (details.isSuccesful == true)` or something like that. What should I type in place of "inSuccesful"? If you would send clearer instructions this wouldn't take so long. But I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209643/discussion-between-peter-and-preston-phx).

Comment: if(details.status == 'COMPLETED') { alert(1);  }  else  {  alert(2);  } ... if anything apart from this you have done , please do let  us know also .